# How to send password in SOAP message

Tags: c++, soap

I have one web application which is display data using SOAP. it's working fine. In my web application I have one page which is display FTP user and password information and that information is coming from SOAP. In that SOAP message password comes as clear text means not encrypted. So, I want to hide or send this information in secure way.

Is there any way to do this ? Because I have no idea. SOAP message coming from Embedded board and server written in C++

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario,

> User<---over web----->Web-App<---SOAP----> Embedded Board(C++).

I think, if just change it to below should work and should be considered safe/secure, if you are only worried about the network interception.

> User<---Over web(make it https)----->Web-App<---SOAP(Make it https)----> Embedded Board(C++).

Even if call could remain HTTP below communication is under your organization firewall and within Internal network.

> Web-App<---SOAP(http should be OK if behind org firewall/intranet)----> Embedded Board(C++).

Comment: Thanks @Red Boy. Is it secure after  using HTTPS ?

Comment: @hkachhia, yes because data transfer happens between server and client with encryption, hence no one could intercept or decode your data over the network. Hence it will be secure.

Comment: Okay. One more thing if user use postman to send SOAP message then  how we force to use HTTPS ?

Comment: You could force https in spring boot app [see](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/). If you will be using web-server(e.g. nginx, Apache or IIS), where anything coming to `http` would redirect to `https`. This will block even postman `http` requests and do redirect to `https`. Hence users will have no choice then using `https`